# Microsoft Graph API permission to patch Application

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

When using the `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default` API to PATCH an Application in Azure AD it fails with the error:

> "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
>       "message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.", ...

The call authenticates by Application permissions and the following are configured: `Application.ReadWrite.All`, `Directory.ReadWrite.All`.

```
$uri = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token";
$resourceUrl = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default'

$body = @{ grant_type='client_credentials';client_id=$clientId;client_secret=$clientSecret;scope=$resourceUrl; }
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $uri -Body $body
$accessToken = $result.access_token
$authHeader = "Bearer $accessToken"

$patchBody = '{
  "displayName" : "dev2"
}'

Invoke-RestMethod -method PATCH -Uri https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/$($app.Id) -Body $patchBody -ContentType application/json -Headers @{Authorization = $AuthHeader }
```

Here is the API permission:

[image: Application API permissions]
Note: I do have access to perform a GET operation for the Application.

Is it possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The Application permission `Application.ReadWrite.All` is enough, make sure you grant it in `Microsoft Graph`, not `Azure Active Directory Graph`, and don't forget to click the `Grant admin consent` button.

[image]

In your script, you should not pass the `$body` in the last line, the `$body` is used to get access token. And make sure this part `$($app.Id)` is the `ObjectId` of the application.

```
$body = @{ grant_type='client_credentials';client_id=$clientId;client_secret=$clientSecret;scope=$resourceUrl; }

Invoke-RestMethod -method PATCH -Uri https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/$($app.Id) -Body $body -ContentType application/json -Headers @{Authorization = $AuthHeader }
```

You need to use the body in this link [`Update application - Request body`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#request-body), you could store it in the `.json` file, then use `Get-Content` to get it.

In my sample, I update the `appRoles`, you could refer to it as below.

The `patch.json` file:

```
{
 "appRoles": [
   {
    "allowedMemberTypes": [
      "User"
    ],
    "description": "Creators can create Surveys",
    "displayName": "SurveyCreator",
    "id": "1b4f816e-5eaf-48b9-8613-7923830595ad",
    "isEnabled": false,
    "value": "SurveyCreator"
  }
 ]
}
```

**Script**:

```
$uri = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token";
$resourceUrl = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default'

$body = @{ grant_type='client_credentials';client_id=$clientId;client_secret=$clientSecret;scope=$resourceUrl; }
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $uri -Body $body
$accessToken = $result.access_token
$authHeader = "Bearer $accessToken"

$body1 = Get-Content -Path "C:\Users\joyw\Desktop\patch.json"

Invoke-RestMethod -method PATCH -Uri https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/<Object-id> -Body $body1 -ContentType application/json -Headers @{Authorization = $AuthHeader }
```

After running the command, you could use `GET` method to check the result.

```
Invoke-RestMethod -method GET -Uri https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/<Object-id> -ContentType application/json -Headers @{Authorization = $AuthHeader }
```

[image]

### Update:

If you use this as the body, it will also work.

```
$patchBody = '{
  "displayName" : "dev2"
}'
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your response. I am using Application.ReadWrite.All for Microsoft Graph, and JSON in the PATCH body although I missed it in my original code snippet. I get the access error.

Comment: @user3167162 See my update. Was the error fixed now?

Comment: @user3167162 Could you show the `API permissions` page of your AD app which you used to get the token in your question?

Comment: Sure, I added it in the question.

Comment: @user3167162 The permission is right. Could you decode the token in the https://jwt.io/, and see if the `Application.ReadWrite.All` is included in the `roles`? Refer to the screenshot - https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcuer.png

Comment: Application.ReadWrite.All is included in the token.

Comment: @user3167162 Does this part `$($app.Id)` be the object-id of another app?

Comment: No, it's the same App, I retrieved from the API: (Invoke-RestMethod -method GET -Uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/" -Headers @{ Authorization = $authHeader }).Value | ? { $_.AppId -eq $clientId }

Comment: @user3167162 It's so weird, could you create a new app to have a try? All work fine on my side. Just give the only `Application.ReadWrite.All` permission.

Comment: I cleared out several other API permissions I had configured in addition Application.ReadWrite.All to and it now seems to work. I'm going to try and reproduce it again to verify this was a cause.

Comment: It fails when the ```Application.Read.All``` permission is added to the list. I guess this is a bug. Thanks you were very helpful.

Comment: @user3167162 I also have a test with adding the `Application.Read.All`, it also works fine. It seems not to be the cause. I think you can try to revoke all the permissions and grant the `Application.ReadWrite.All` again or create a new app.

Comment: @user3167162 Glad it works now, if my reply is helpful, please accept it, thanks.:-)

Comment: @user3167162 Hi, any other concern?

Comment: Hi @joywang can you reproduce it by adding the ```Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy``` permission?

Comment: @user3167162 Incredible, I reproduced the error, maybe a bug. I also decode the token, the `Application.ReadWrite.All` is included.